# How to implement password expiration and password archivable features using amazon cognito

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, devise, amazon-cognito

I have a Ruby on rails application, i have integrated `AWS Cognito` to achieve SSO. It's all working.Earlier to that I was using `devise` for authentication and to achieve `password_expirable` and `password_archivable`.I searched through [Amazon docs for ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentity/Client.html) but could not find any way to achieve it.

I am looking for some example or guidance to achieve the same using `AWS Cognito`.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no in built support for password expiry in Cognito. Something which can be considered for future releases.

For security reasons Cognito only stores SRP password verifier, so there is no way to check the history of saved passwords and match is against the new one. So this is unlikely to be implemented in future.

Answer (score 0):

By nature of SSO, the users will likely be authenticating with their Facebook, Google+, Microsoft accounts.  You don't want to force them to reset their password on these accounts do you?

Would Multi-Factor-Authentication (MFA) better suit your security requirements?

If so, you you can set up a [User Pool](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-your-user-pools-in-amazon-cognito/) with Amazon Cognito.  With a User Pool, you can get programmatic access to the User Pool and [enforce MFA](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html#user-pool-settings-mfa). Then, via Amazon SNS or email, the users can be authenticated via phone or email.

Answer (score 0):

To force users to reset their passwords, Cognito's pre-authentication trigger event can be used. Have a field in user pool, which checks password's age. If it exceeds the determined age, then have a Lamdba trigger generate an event to force the user to change the password by using AdminResetUserPassword API. Make sure to update password's age, whenever user updates his/her password, as part of other password change flows (Forgot Password flow) as well.